# Stiching top down photos of long items using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, emgucv, image-stitching

I'm working on a project that includes taking top-down photos from three stationary cameras mounted above a long white table. Long packs of veneer are placed on the table to be photographed. The three images then need to be stitched together. The goal is to achieve a smooth transition on the border. I'm trying to use OpenCV to achieve this, but I'm running into problems. The images are either stitched with huge overlap and distortion or, most commonly, just give an "assertion failed" error. I've tried using both "panorama" and "scans" modes to no avail. I'm using the Emgu.CV.NET wrapper, but the logic behind it should be the same.

The reason I'm not joining images manually is due to slight chromatic distortions towards the edges of images, which cause the pack size to slightly differ in the place where the connection should be. Also, the exact position of cameras may shift over time, causing further shifts. I was hoping the existing algorithms could fix that.

Am I using the `stitcher` wrongly, or is it unfit for this task? Can someone recommend other tools or methods for this problem?

Here's example images, which error out the `stitcher`.

[image]
[image]
[image]

(Click to see full-size versions)

Code used:

```
class ImageStitching
{
    public static Mat StichImages(List<Mat> images)
    {
        Mat output = new Mat();

        VectorOfMat matVector = new VectorOfMat();

        foreach (Mat img in images)
        {
            matVector.Push(img);
        }

        Stitcher stitcher = new Stitcher(Emgu.CV.Stitching.Stitcher.Mode.Scans);

        Brisk detector = new Brisk();

        stitcher.SetFeaturesFinder(detector);
        stitcher.Stitch(matVector, output);

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: what you do fails for multiple reasons. one is that your table has no features. another is that you actually use the stitching module wrong. for **your situation**, you are supposed to **calibrate** your cameras once, or rather, you calibrate the stitching once. that info is **kept and reused**. then, only based on the calibration, you stitch new images.